# Length of projection onto a subspace equal length of the vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If the length of the projection of a vector onto a subspace equals the length of the vector, does this always imply that the vector belongs to that subspace. 
This was quite easy to show when the projection is from a vector to another vector and the angle between them is strictly acute. 
I would kindly need some hint in the case of projection to a subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your vector is $v$ and subspace is $U$, you get $v=u+h$ with $u\in U$ and $(u,h)=0$. Then $(v,v)=(u,u)+(h,h)$, so $(v,v)=(u,u)$ implies $(h,h)=0$ which means $h=0$.

Comment: Thank you very much.. This is Really Great....